# jenkins auto login disable

Tags: jenkins

I want to disable Jenkins auto login.
When I open the jenkins on browser like `http://192.168.5.15:8080`  , it does not ask `user id` and `password` .

when I go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security >`  there I do not get an option to tick out `Enable Security`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your security realm is set to `None`.  You can't enable security (i.e. account login) if you have no user accounts.  You need to tell Jenkins where to look for user accounts.

If you want to use your local machine's credentials, use "Unix user/group database".  If you created an admin account during setup, then it was probably stored in "Jenkin's own user database".  I use LDAP to connect with my organization's active directory.

---

To be sure this answer is correct, I installed a fresh instance of Jenkins on a debian system and set up an initial admin user.  Then I set `"Security Realm" = None` and `"Authorization"=Anyone can do anything`.  In this situation, I was able to access the security settings in an incognito browser (no login).  I think this is the same situation you have.

Next I selected: `"Security Realm"=Jenkins’ own user database` with `Authorization=Logged-in users can do anything` and ensured that `Allow anonymous read access` was not selected.

I refreshed my incognito browser and I had a sign-in prompt, requiring login before I could see anything at all.  I confirm that I could login with the admin-account I created during installation.